# SQL Nested Query slow using IN

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I have the WordNet lexical database in MySQL.  I am looking to find synonyms of given words.  Currently the data is set out in three tables as a many-to-many relationship:

**words** - (147,000 rows)

 wordid, word

**synsets** - (119,000 rows)

 synsetid

**sense** - (206,000 rows)

wordid, synsetid

All tables have indexes set up on them.

Each word can have several synsets and each synset can have several words.  I am looking to return all words for all synsets for a given word.  There tends to be around 2 synsets for each word (one for the verb usage, one for the noun) The SQL query I'm using for this is:

```
SELECT w.word
FROM sense s
INNER JOIN words w
ON s.wordid = w.wordid
WHERE s.synsetid 
IN
(
SELECT s.synsetid
FROM words w
INNER JOIN sense s
ON w.wordid = s.wordid 
WHERE w.word = "word_to_search"
)
AND w.word <> 'word_to_search' ORDER BY synsetid
```

This seems to be taking a very long time however (~0.75 secs).  When you split the queries up they take ~0.0005 secs for the inner query and similar for each of the outer queries.

So what am I doing wrong?  Is there a much more appropriate way to structure this query?

**EDIT:**

So the solution I have come up with after reading the linked articles below is:

```
SELECT w.word
FROM sense s
INNER JOIN words w
ON s.wordid = w.wordid
JOIN
(
SELECT s.synsetid
FROM words w
INNER JOIN sense s
ON w.wordid = s.wordid 
WHERE w.word = "word_to_search"
) i
ON i.synsetid = s.synsetid
```

This executes in ~0.0008 sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[avoiding IN and NOT IN](http://www.componentworkshop.com/blog/2009/06/26/sql-server-basics-avoiding-in-and-not-in) (in your case just IN) with `INNER JOIN ON` could boost performance.

**edit:**

These links:

[link 1](http://explainextended.com/2009/06/16/in-vs-join-vs-exists/)

[link 2](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/)

research the effectiveness of JOINS vs IN's and other interchangeable operations. They, however, conclude that IN and NOT IN **does not** need to be avoided.

Comment: Using a JOIN risks duplication if the child table has more than one record relating to the parent

Comment: @OMGPonies I'm no expert but that seems easy to avoid (using some non-inner join or smart where-clause)

Comment: Thanks, this answers the 'what am I doing wrong' section.  I was unaware that the DB does not work out the inner query first.  I am still at a loss of how to better structure the query though.

Comment: @Jahnold You might want to read [this](http://explainextended.com/2009/06/16/in-vs-join-vs-exists/) and [this](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/). They are not in favor of the JOIN. Sry if I'm confusing you :p (links suggested by [michael buen](http://stackoverflow.com/users/11432/michael-buen))

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this (Updated)

```
SELECT w2.word, synsetid
FROM words w
INNER JOIN synset s  on  s.wordId = w.wordID
INNER JOIN words2 w2 on w2.wordID = s.wordID
WHERE w.word = "word_to_search"
GROUP BY w2.word, synsetid
ORDER BY synsetid, w2.word
```

Now I think I understand what you want.  All words within the same synset as the requested word.

Comment: This is throwing up an error: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE w.word = "word_to_search" GROUP BY w.word, synsetid ORDER BY synsetid, w.w' at line 5

It doesn't seem to like the 'and'

Comment: removed the and it was an artifact of copy and paste and eliminating the sub select

Comment: Thanks, this just returns the 'word_to_search' and it's associated synsets though.  It doesn't return all the other words in the synset.

Comment: ah I failed to understand the premise.  I've updated to account for what I know think you're after.  after my edit however, if there are no other related words, nothing will be returned. I'd think you'd at least want the original word; but perhaps not.