# How can I improve a slow custom query? (subquery + inner joins with custom fields)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a query that is used to return available rooms for a booking system

Using [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/), I have a custom post type representing reservation with various fields

The plan here is to find all the booked rooms with the subquery, and then get all the available rooms by selecting the posts who are not in the result set returned by the subquery

My reservation custom posts have a "terrain_id" who is supposed to match the post id of the rooms (Camping or cottages)

The first inner join is for the room ID (terrain_id), the second inner join is for the start date, and the last one is for the end date

So basically I match the room_id with the post_id and return all the unavailable rooms for the specified time interval, and then I get all the IDS who aren't present in the subquery result to get my available rooms

The problem is the following :

This query runs in about 5-6 seconds on a tiny data sample (about 2000 reservations, and 100 rooms)

I tried different ways to optimize it but I am pretty much stuck

There are indexes on all the relevant fields

The subquery itself runs in about 0.030 seconds so I don't think the inner joins are the issues here, the bulk of the problem seems to be in SELECT where NOT EXISTS

Using default wordpress methods and the loop is not option since it's not possible to do what is need and I would need to query all the custom fields individually for each records

How can I improve my query performance?

How can select basic attributes where not present in an array of about 100 records can take so long?

```
SELECT wps.ID, wps.post_title, wps.post_type, wps.post_status
FROM wp_posts wps, wp_postmeta wpm
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT
      p.ID,
      pm_ti.meta_value as tiv,
      pm_ti.meta_key as tik,
      pm_ed.meta_key as edk,
      pm_ed.meta_value as edv,
      pm_sd.meta_key as sdk,
      pm_sd.meta_value as sdv
    FROM
      wp_posts p
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm_ti ON (pm_ti.post_id = p.ID )
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm_ed ON (pm_ed.post_id = p.ID )
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm_sd ON (pm_sd.post_id = p.ID )
    WHERE NOT (pm_ed.meta_value <= '{$start}' OR pm_sd.meta_value >= '{$end}')
    AND pm_ti.meta_key='terrain_id' and p.post_status='publish' and wps.ID = pm_ti.meta_value and pm_ed.meta_key='e_date' and pm_sd.meta_key='s_date'
    GROUP BY p.ID
)
AND wpm.post_id = wps.ID AND wps.post_status='publish' AND wps.ID = icl_translations.element_id
and (wps.post_type='camping' or wps.post_type='cottages') GROUP BY wps.ID
");
```

Explain result :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally manage to find a decent answer

The source of the problem was the fact that nested queries like these are inherently slow, so I replaced the WHERE ... NOT IN with a negative LEFT OUTER JOIN

I started by optimizing the inner query since it was sloppy and the same result could be achieved in a simpler way

Then, by replacing the WHERE condition with a LEFT OUTER JOIN to obtain the same result

This question was very helpful :

[SQL Nested Query slow using IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666531/sql-nested-query-slow-using-in)

Original query took between 5 and 15 seconds,

The modified query run in less that 0.05 seconds

```
SELECT wps.ID, wps.post_title, pm_ti.meta_value

FROM wp_posts wps

LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(

   SELECT
   pm_ti.meta_value
   FROM
   wp_postmeta pm_ti
   INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm_ed ON (pm_ed.post_id = pm_ti.post_id )
   INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm_sd ON (pm_sd.post_id = pm_ti.post_id )
   WHERE NOT (pm_ed.meta_value <= '2014-07-01' OR pm_sd.meta_value >= '2014-07-12')
   AND pm_ti.meta_key='terrain_id' AND pm_ed.meta_key='e_date' AND pm_sd.meta_key='s_date'

) pm_ti

ON wps.ID = pm_ti.meta_value

INNER JOIN wp_icl_translations icl ON (icl.element_id = wps.ID)

WHERE pm_ti.meta_value IS null AND wps.post_status='publish' 

AND (wps.post_type='camping' OR wps.post_type='cottages')  AND icl.language_code = 'fr'

GROUP BY wps.ID
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your data well enough to write this 100% but the idea here is the same. Instead of using a correlated subquery try something like this.

```
SELECT wps.ID, wps.post_title, wps.post_type, wps.post_status
FROM wp_posts wps, wp_postmeta wpm
WHERE wpm.post_id NOT IN
(
    SELECT
      DISTINCT pm_ti.meta_value
    FROM
      wp_posts p
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm_ti ON (pm_ti.post_id = p.ID )
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm_ed ON (pm_ed.post_id = p.ID )
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm_sd ON (pm_sd.post_id = p.ID )
    WHERE NOT (pm_ed.meta_value <= '{$start}' OR pm_sd.meta_value >= '{$end}')
    AND pm_ti.meta_key='terrain_id'
    AND p.post_status='publish'
    AND pm_ed.meta_key='e_date'
    AND pm_sd.meta_key='s_date'
)
AND wpm.post_id = wps.ID
AND wps.post_status='publish'
AND wps.ID = icl_translations.element_id
AND (wps.post_type='camping' or wps.post_type='cottages')
```

The idea is to return a list of IDs that you don't want in one select that not linked to the primary select. Then you filter your main select using NOT IN.

Just something to try - not tested.

Comment: The query is way faster, but the problem is that instead of p.ID, the primary key needs to be the meta_key 'terrain_id'. I'm trying to get it to work and I'll report back

Comment: I updated this to return the terrain_id value and compare it to the post_id, but it really doesn't make any sense since you are setting the id equal to the post_id anyhow. I'm very confused by your database. It might just be that I'm way to tired to think now.

Comment: @Bob - it's the standard WordPress database structure.  It's based on the [TOXI Solution](http://tagging.pui.ch/post/37027745720/tags-database-schemas) tagging structure, and therefore it's confusing.

Comment: The subquery is used to find the available rooms, the POST ID is the reservation number and the 'terrain_id' is the room number, so I need the room number instead of the reservation number to find available room by number. But yes, I agree, the structure is quite confusing. I tried some tweaks but the query still runs in about 5 seconds. As with my first query, the problem still reside in the SELECT WHERE wps.post_ID NOT IN, which takes pretty much 90% of the query time